# Regular expression where * matches all characters except back slash and new line

Tags: c#, regex, git, gitignore

Here is what I'm trying to implement

Link to gitignore documentation: [gitignore manpage](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitignore.html)

> Otherwise, git treats the pattern as a shell glob suitable for consumption by fnmatch(3) with the FNM_PATHNAME flag: wildcards in the pattern will not match a / in the pathname. For example, "Documentation/*.html"* matches "Documentation/git.html" but not "Documentation/ppc/ppc.html" or "tools/perf/Documentation/perf.html".

I did try this in code

```
patternEscapedForStar = patternEscaped.Replace(@"\*", "[^\\]*");
```

The above line is to change the behavior of * in regular expression to match all the characters except "\" in the file or folder path. However it does not seem to match as expected. Since I'm using gitignore patterns, I did convert blob to regular expression before the replace I mentioned above.

By the way I dabble in regular expressions and is not expert in any way. Thanks for your help.

EDIT:

Here is complete code

```
public static bool PatternMatch(string str, string pattern, string type)
{
string patternEscaped = string.Empty;
string patternEscapedForStar = string.Empty;                                              
string patternEscapedForQuestionMark = string.Empty;
bool returnValue = false;

try
{
    patternEscaped = Regex.Escape(pattern);

    patternEscapedForStar = patternEscaped.Replace(@"\*", ".*");
    if (type == "P")
    {
        patternEscapedForStar = patternEscapedForStar.Replace(@".*", "[^\\]*");
    }

    patternEscapedForQuestionMark = patternEscapedForStar.Replace(@"\?", ".");

    returnValue = new Regex(patternEscapedForQuestionMark, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline).IsMatch(str);

 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
     Log.LogException(ex);
 }
    return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: Are you **definitely** certain, that your input string `patternEscaped` contains `"\\*"` and not just `"*"` ?

Comment: @Nolonar The input string contains just "*" I'm replacing that with > [^\\]* (zero or more characters except "\". Since it is windows the second "\" is for escape in the string.

Comment: "does not seem to match as expected". Can you give a `verbatim` example?

Comment: The thing is; your code seems to be using `string.Replace()` to replace `@"\*"` (aka `"\\*"`) with `"[^\\]*"`. For strings, `*` is a valid character and does not need to be escaped. Try `patternEscaped.Replace("*", "[^\\]*")` instead.

Comment: @Nolonar

    pattern: folder*\folder111
    string:  folder11\folder111\somefile.txt

this still gives me false and does not match, I did change
    "\\*" to "*"

Comment: @Floris I just posted the pattern and string I'm trying with. Sorry for the delay.

Comment: @Nolonar Here is the error I'm getting when I try with above string and patter

    {"parsing \"folder[^\\]*\\\\folder111\" - Unterminated [] set."}

Comment: I posted an answer with the solution. Sorry I didn't spot the obvious mistake earlier.

Comment: @Nolonar The second part of answer worked. Thanks so much, Nolonar. I accepted your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're facing, is because of `"[^\\]*"`. Since `\` is used to describe escape characters, `"\\"` resolves to the literal `\` character, which is the only character your `Regex` will see.

And that's where everything blows up; Since `\` is also a special character for `Regex`, we get the problem, that `Regex` doesn't really know what to do with `@"[^\]*"`.

Long story short: The correct answer is

```
patternEscapedForStar = patternEscaped.Replace(@"\*", @"[^\\]*");
```

or

```
patternEscapedForStar = patternEscaped.Replace(@"\*", "[^\\\\]*");
```

Comment: patternEscapedForStar = patternEscaped.Replace(@"\\*", "[^\\\\\]*");

This worked. You are awesome! Thanks so much for your help. I did accept your answer however I cannot upvote the answer since I do not have enough points yet. Thanks again.

Comment: I tried that however it gives me the same error I posted earlier. Also in the very first comment I meant 
    [^\\\] however one slash was removed as I posted. I guess it was a good thing as the alternate answer to that worked.
Thanks again.

Comment: I see. Not sure why the first part of the answer wouldn't work, but I'm glad it helped.